# php - can't get the result of a query to output. (if there is an output)

Tags: php

The program takes a variable $ask from a user which is a category of an interest such as sport, movies etc. then checks the database if that category exists, if it doesn't exist it adds it to the database. database memory, table - 'interestcategories' which at the moment just has 3 columns IID, Category and Comment. Adding to the database works however if it is in the database, printing out what is in there doesn't work....

The problem mostly lies in these lines:

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Category"], $row["Comment"]);
   }
   /* free result set */
   mysqli_free_result($result);
```

As nothing gets put to screen not even an error msg. 
There should only ever be printed one line, as the category only appears once in the table. 
Any ideas?

```
  <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "memory");
  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
  }

function notAnInterest($ask, $link)
{
$query2 = "INSERT into interestcategories (Category, Comment)
        VALUES ('$ask', 'Added by user') ";

$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2);
echo "<pre>Debug: $query2</pre>\n";
if ( false===$result2 ) {
  printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link)); 
  }
 echo 'added ' . $ask; 
 }

 if(isset($_POST['ask']) === true && empty($_POST['ask']) === false) {
 $ask = trim($_POST['ask']);
$query = "
SELECT  *
FROM    `interestcategories`
WHERE `interestcategories`.`Category` = '$ask' ";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
if(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) === null) {
notAnInterest($ask, $link);
}
 /* fetch associative array */
    printf('here1');
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf('here2');
  //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Category"], $row["Comment"]);
}

 /* free result set */
 mysqli_free_result($result);
}

}

 /* close connection */
  mysqli_close($link);

  ?>
```

Comment: try to enable error reporting on as "error_reporting(E_ALL);"

Comment: which line do I add that to, at the start?                                  I have narrowed the problem down to this part                       /* fetch associative array */
 printf('here1');
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ('here2');
    }                                                                  as 'here1' gets printd but not 'here2'

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); add at the top, it will display if there is any error..

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Should I use something besides while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) if it is just returning 1 line?

Comment: I was not using msql_ functions, I was using mysqli_

Comment: @LindsayW `mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['ask']));`

Comment: @LindsayW that is probably what is causing your problem too. Yes, you are otherwise using MySQLi, but you are not using prepared statements.

Comment: cryptic thanks for picking that up, changed that line of code and added error_reporting(E_ALL) however still nothing is being printed - and no errors.

Comment: @LindsayW can you please update your question with the updated version of code so everyone is kept on the same page?

Comment: updated now. I may be using while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) incorrectly?

Comment: @LindsayW, I'm refactoring your code so its easier to read, will help you spot mistakes more easily.

Comment: @LindsayW, please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) 
{
    if (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) === null) 
    {
        notAnInterest($ask, $link);
    }

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row['Category'], $row['Comment']);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

To:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) 
{
    if (0 == mysqli_num_rows($result)) 
    {
        notAnInterest($ask, $link);
    }
    else
    {
        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row['Category'], $row['Comment']);
        }
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: not sure I see your point, as notAnInterest($ask, $link) is only run if $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) === null.

Comment: @LindsayW, run the above code and tell me the output you get you browser, you should get letters. Will help us see where it has failed.

Comment: Animals (which wasn't in the database gets):                             cdea
Debug: INSERT INTO `interestcategories` (`Category`, `Comment`)
        VALUES ('animals', 'Added by user')
added animalsg                                                        Sport which was in the database gets: cdg

Comment: Thanks cryptic, that worked fine. It printed the output correctly. Was the problem due to using mysqli_fetch_assoc.. twice?